# how to save my profile and my user so I will continue from other PC

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I need to replace my PC with other new PC

I want to continue with my stack-overflow User on the new PC
Please advice what need to do in order to  save all my user profile so on the other New pc I will can ask question as today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your profile is stored on the StackOverflow servers, so all you need to do is start up a browser on your new PC, go to stackoverflow.com, log in via your preferred method, and voilà: you're logged in to StackOverflow.

Comment: about what you said - "log in via your preferred method" you mean that I need to log with my OLD email and real name ?

Comment: @Eytan - you speak as if you've never logged into the same website from multiple PCs before. However, it can we weird signing into SO with an existing OAuth account. I suspect it's actually possible to forget what emails and passwords you are actually using. You can start by going to http://stackoverflow.com/users/1121951/eytan and clicking the "my logins" link in the top right corner to see what account you are currently signed in with.